# django: two fields of different classes one loop?

Tags: python, django, view

Sorry for digging deeper, thought my errors would be easy to fix but since hours i dont get along with it. Updated working code:

View:

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = TodoItem.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.list.tag }}
    {{ post.width }}
{% endfor %}
```

Models:

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
   tag = ...

class TodoItem(models.Model):
   width = ...
   list = models.ForeignKey(TodoList, related_name="list_items")
```

`{{ post.list.tag }}` and `list = models.ForeignKey` did the trick!

Everything working fine **but** because with `TodoItems` i can add forms dynamicly, most of the time i've more fields on `TodoItems` then on `TodoList`. 
So my Problem is when i render the loop like above i have the following output:

tag:width, tag:width, tag:width, tag:width, ...

What i need is to loop through `TodoList` instead of `TodoItem` where i expected following output:

tag: width, width, width | tag: width, width ...

(number of width is dynamicly added but when i add for example 4 times `width` there only should be one related `tag`)
I tried a lot here a nearby example

View: `TodoList` instead of `TodoItem`

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = TodoList.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

but then at the template `TodoList` output failed. I spare u my tries on template.
Can anyone please help me out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to change your views. i think and i hope that you have one-to-many (ForeignKey) from List to Items

in this case, just do in your template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
   {{ post.list.tag }} 
   {{ post.width }}
{% endfor %}
```

and your models would look like this:

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
   name = ... 
   tag = ...

class TodoItem(models.Model):
   # ...
   list = models.ForeignKey(TodoList, related_name="list_items")
```

Comment: wow thanks worked! Now other Probs xD but thats another story. ty so much